# Syntax error when processData is false for $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to send DOM document in an ajax call.

I have the following ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://someurl.com",
  processData: false,
  contentType: "application/javascript",
  json: 'jsonp',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true,
  data: data
});
```

where

```
data = {
  content: $('#somediv').get(0)
}
```

This always results to a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` everytime I add `processData: false`

I tried `data: JSON.stringify(data)` where no syntax error occurs but the data still wasn't handled right (ajax call returning an error).

Comment: why you want to send DOM object as itself ?

Comment: because the API function I'm calling requires a DOMDocument, @Sarath

Comment: Can we know what's the API you're talking about ?

Comment: have you tried `data = {
  content: $('#somediv:nth-child(0)')
}`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything else that "content" in data? Because if not, why not send the HTML code directly (as html, not as json)? Then use `$(data).get(0)` to convert the jQuery object into a DOM object.